# How to tell PEAR where to extract the downloaded files?

Tags: deployment, extract, pear, package

I set up a local pear repository/client, however you call it. I discovered a channel and already downloaded a package, which worked fine. As far as I know pear separates the php and data files in two folders, after it extracted the files. But I want ALL files being together in one directory which I can specify. How can I do this?

I already tried:

`pear config-set data_dir my-specified-directory`

`pear config-set php_dir my-specified-directory`

But that does not work because it expects directories called `data` and `php`. Is there any way to do this? Background: I use pear to deploy packages on a test server and I need everything in one directory to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found it:

`pear config-set www_dir my-specified-directory`